# Is pytorch 1.7 officially enabled for cuda 10.0?

Tags: installation, pytorch

I had to stay on CUDA 10.0 for personal projects.

Rather than installing Pytorch with versions appropriate for CUDA 10.0, I accidentally installed Pytorch 1.7 supported with CUDA 10.1. In particular, I installed it by

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cu101 torchvision==0.8.2+cu101 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Surprisingly, everything works fine so far although the CUDA versions do not match.

To verify my installation, I've run the code given in [`collect_env.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/torch/utils/collect_env.py), and it was fine.

I am just wondering a few things.

1. Did the Pytorch team officially comment Pytorch 1.7 is compatible with CUDA 10.0?
2. Would there be more rigorous ways to verify my Pytorch installation?

Comment: Please stop tagging this question with the CUDA tag. This isn't a CUDA programming related question in any on-topic question for [SO]. The systems requirements for a particular version of Pytorch are, unsurprisingly enough, a question about Pytorch, not a question about the individual components on which it relies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surprisingly, everything works fine so far although the CUDA versions do not match.

Changes between minor versions should work (mismatch like this worked in my case), although there is no promise of compatibility in `10.x` release ([source](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html)), only since `11.x` there will be [binary compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-code_compatibility).

> Did the Pytorch team officially comment Pytorch 1.7 is compatible with CUDA 10.0?

Not that I'm aware of, but [listed wheels](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html) **do not include** `10.0` CUDA and PyTorch `1.7.0` (latest with `10.0` support seems to be `1.4.0`).

> Would there be a more rigorous way to verify my Pytorch installation?

As above, maybe cloning PyTorch's GitHub repo, reverting to tagged release, and running tests (folder [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/test), one of cuda test files [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/test/test_cuda.py)), but for personal projects might be excessive.

Comment: This does not work if the driver version does not support the corresponding cuda version. For my case, a warning is through out (after running `torch.cuda.is_available()`): `UserWarning: CUDA initialization: The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old.`

Answer (score 1):

The [Pytorch Previous Version Log](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) offers installations for CUDA versions 9.2, 10.1, 10.2 and 11. Therefore, CUDA 10 is probably not officially supported.